# Show data in listview from airport

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am doing a project where I want to display a list of airports in a ListView. The airports names are retrieved from the local database.
Actually i get all data from database in sqliteopenhelper class

```
public List<AirportList> getAllAirportLists()
    {

        List<AirportList> airportList = new ArrayList<AirportList>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_AIRPORT;
        Log.i("query", selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                AirportList airport = new AirportList();
                airport.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                airport.setName(cursor.getString(1));

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return airportList;

    }
```

and iam new to android  can any one please give an idea for call this method in main class and show the airport list in listview.

Comment: check this : http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-show-data-from-sqlite-db-into.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in the method above you need to add your airport objects in "airportList" like:

> `public List getAllAirportLists() {

```
List<AirportList> airportList = new ArrayList<AirportList>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_AIRPORT;
Log.i("query", selectQuery);

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do{
        AirportList airport = new AirportList();
        airport.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        airport.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        airportList.add(airport);
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}

return airportList;
```

}`

then assign this list in your listView in main Class. like:

> ```
> listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
> listView.setAdapter(new AppAdapter(airportList));
> ```

```
class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AirportList> {

        AppAdapter(List<AirportList> itemList) {
            super(YourAcitivity.this, R.layout.airport_item_list, itemList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = newView(parent);

            }
            bindView(position, convertView);
            return convertView;
        }

        private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
            return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.airport_item_list, parent,
                    false);
        }

        private void bindView(int position, View row) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

hey First check the below tutorials

simple listview [simple list](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/simple-listview-android-developer.html)

custom listview [custom listview](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)

before creating the adapter get list from data and added to adapter.